# Given Size in Terminal Row and Column units, how to calculate equivalent number pixels

Tags: linux, bash, wayland, terminal-emulator

I have a program which makes available 2 shell variables `$width` and `$height`, which
are the desired width and desired height in "rows" and "columns"  of an output (in this case a sixel image) to the terminal.

How would I go about converting these $height and $width values from row/column units
to pixel units?

```
#!/bin/bash
pixelsperrow=# How
pixelspercolumn=# How
heightpixels=$(($height*$pixelsperrow))
widthpixels=$(($width*$pixelspercolumn))
```

I also noticed my terminal emulator (`foot`) provides an environment variable
$COLUMNS which is the current number of column available in the terminal window. I am using `river` (a wayland tiling window manager) as my WM if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `ioctl` that, maybe, can obtain the terminal dimensions in pixels:

```
$ cat termsize.c
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    printf("%d,%d %d,%d\n", w.ws_row, w.ws_col, w.ws_ypixel, w.ws_xpixel);
    return 0;
}
$ make termsize
cc     termsize.c   -o termsize
$ ./termsize
24,80 388,644
```

Comment: "maybe" (but it depends on the underlying terminal).